# Large table updates using AJAX in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I have a website which **only needs to support IE11**. It is a single page application, which has about **200 table rows** and each table row has **5 child rows**.

There is a pulsing function that updates the table **as records come in**. Table rows are skipped over if no update comes in.

However, when receiving large updates (which should only occasionally happening), the application will hang as it slowly processes the javascript. I've tried to limit the JavaScript as much as possible, but still have a long running function.

I am a backend developer by nature, and was wondering if anyone had any tips to help support large table Ajax updates for IE since IE so poorly handles JS.

```
function writeTableLines(tempRows){
    /* This Function takes care of updating the text and coloring of
    required dynamic fields. 
    All other values are not dynamically written.
    */
    for( i in tempRows){
   //i is the computer name
        tempValues = tempRows[i];
        // For Row
        selector = "[id='"+i+"']";

        // Network Name
        network_selector = "[id='"+i+"_network']";
        $(network_selector).text(tempValues['network']);

        if (tempValues['network_color']){
            $(network_selector).addClass(tempValues['network_color']);
            $(selector).find('.name').addClass(tempValues['network_color']);
        }else{
            $(network_selector).removeClass('warning');
             $(selector).find('.name').removeClass('warning');
        }

        // Boot Time
        boot_selector = "[id='"+i+"_boot']";
        $(boot_selector).text(tempValues['boot']);
        if (tempValues['boot_color']){
            $(boot_selector).addClass(tempValues['boot_color']);
            $(selector).find('.name').addClass(tempValues['boot_color'])
        }else{
            $(boot_selector).removeClass('issue');
            $(selector).find('.name').removeClass('issue');
        }

        // Last Checked In Timestamp
        check_in_selector = "[id='"+i+"_checked_in']";
        $(check_in_selector).text(tempValues['checked_in']);
        if (tempValues['service_unresponsive']){
            $(check_in_selector).addClass('redline');
            $(selector).find('.name').addClass('redline');
        }else{
            $(check_in_selector).removeClass('redline');
            $(selector).find('.name').removeClass('redline');
        }

        util_selector = $(selector).find('td.util').find('a');
        $(util_selector).text(tempValues['util'])
         if (tempValues['util_class']){
            $(util_selector).addClass(tempValues['util_class']);
        }else{
            $(util_selector).removeClass('redline warning');
        }

        workgroup_selector = $(selector).find('td.workgroup');

        if (($.trim(tempValues['workgroup'])) != $.trim($(workgroup_selector).text())){
            if ((tempValues['workgroup'] != selected) && (selected != 'All')){
                $(workgroup_selector).addClass('warning');
            }else{
                $(workgroup_selector).removeClass('warning');
            }
        }
        $(workgroup_selector).text(tempValues['workgroup'])
        toggle_links(i, tempRows[i]);
        $('#connectionGrid').trigger('updateAll', [false]);
    }
}
```

This function iterates over only received data. For each row item that was received, update the text of the cell, and add coloring as necessary.

I'm thinking I might just be screwed since its IE, but am open to all suggestions and ideas.

Image of the rows - child rows only available when expanded, but still need updates.

[image]

Comment: XSLT (declarative) may be a more elegant approach to this task than the spaghetti bowl of branch statements that you'd need to write in most imperative languages including JavaScript. CSS selectors are already a great help, but I think you can do better.

Comment: I am not familar with XSLT. Unfortunately :/ I will research it however at your advice

Comment: [XSLT](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) only works, if the responses to the asynchronous update requests contain XML (or (X)HTML) data, obviously. If you're sending JSON, YAML or CSV, my suggestion is moot.

Comment: Searching a large DOM for elements is a real performance killer. If the "network", "boot" and "check_in" elements could be found *relative* to the corresponding "selector" element, similar to the "util" and "workgroup" elements, that alone would  be a significant improvement.

Comment: You might consider wrapping each block (each row plus its subrows) in `<tbody>...</tbody>`, with considerable advantages to element selection and styling. Hard to give concrete advice without seeing the HTML.

Comment: I  can add more tomorrow at work. Tomorrow I think I might try wrapping each block in a `tbody` and create another view which will pump the raw html which will have the appropriate classes etc, and use `$.load()`   ... any thoughts @Roamer-1888

Comment: Certainly worth trying, though I was thinking of sticking with your current approach, just mechanising it better.

Comment: Ive added updated Javascript, (current version of function + the `toggle_links` code. Also added the HTML (uses JINJA template for rendering) If you have any ideas how to mechanise better I would be extremely greatful to hear them @Roamer-1888

Comment: well Im still having issues with responsiveness, I cant even do a 5 computer update :(

Comment: and now all that content I just spent 30 minutes editing is gone :(  . and It had updated function according to his suggestion, as well as addition information requested in these comments

Comment: Ive opened a new question here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/118729/large-table-updates-using-ajax-in-internet-explorer-11-contd @Roamer-1888

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Searching a whole, large DOM for elements is a real performance killer. When possible, always try to search a fragment, or traverse the DOM relative to a known element.

With a little rearrangement of the HTML, "network", "boot" and "check_in" elements can be found within the corresponding "selector" element, similar to the way "util" and "workgroup" elements are currently found. This alone should give a significant performance boost.

**HTML**

- There's a missing `</tr>` somewhere.
- Move `<tbody>` and `</tbody>` inside the loop/if lines to give one tbody per computer block. (Hopefully tbodys will not mess up tablesorter).
- Move `id="{{computer.name}}"` into the `<tbody>` tag.
- Give a class name to elements that need to be addressed :

For example, change :

```
<td class="info" colspan="1" id="{{computer.name}}_network">{{ computer.active_drive.name }}</td>
```

to:

```
<td class="info network" colspan="1" id="{{computer.name}}_network">{{ computer.active_drive.name }}</td>
```

- Then, if they are not required elsewhere, purge all IDs in the repeated block.

**Javascript**

The javascript can now be written to exploit the tbody wrappers.

```
function writeTableLines(tempRows) {
    /* 
     This Function takes care of updating the text and coloring of required dynamic fields. 
     All other values are not dynamically written.
    */
    var tempValues, $tbody, $name, $network, $boot, $check_in, $util, $workgroup,
        $connectionGrid = $('#connectionGrid');

    // Avoid creating so many strings in the loop by defining class names and selectors here.
    // This is more a memory consideration than speed.
    var clss = {
        'warning': 'warning',
        'issue': 'issue',
        'redline': 'redline'
        'redlineWarning': 'redline warning',
    };
    var selectors = {
        'network': '.network',
        'boot': '.boot',
        'check_in': '.checked_in',
        'name': '.name',
        'util': 'td.util a',
        'workgroup': 'td.workgroup'
    };

    for(i in tempRows) {
        tempValues = tempRows[i];

        // Find the container
        $tbody = $('#' + i); // This is the only element in each block that needs an ID.

        if($tbody.length == 0) return; // avoid unnecessary work if element is not found

        // Now find elements by class, within the container
        $network = $tbody.find(selectors.network);
        $boot = $tbody.find(selectors.boot);
        $check_in = $tbody.find(selectors.checked_in);
        $name = $tbody.find(selectors.name);
        $util = $tbody.find(selectors.util);
        $workgroup = $tbody.find(selectors.workgroup);

        // In all the code below, address tempValues properties with dot.notation, not associative['notation']

        $network.text(tempValues.network);
        if (tempValues.network_color) {
            $network.addClass(tempValues.network_color);
            $name.addClass(tempValues.network_color);
        } else {
            $network.removeClass(clss.warning);
            $name.removeClass(clss.warning);
        }

        $boot.text(tempValues.boot);
        if (tempValues.boot_color) {
            $boot.addClass(tempValues.boot_color);
            $name.addClass(tempValues.boot_color);
        } else {
            $boot.removeClass(clss.issue);
            $name.removeClass(clss.issue);
        }

        $check_in.text(tempValues.checked_in);
        if (tempValues.service_unresponsive) {
            $check_in.addClass(clss.redline);
            $name.addClass(clss.redline);
        } else {
            $check_in.removeClass(clss.redline);
            $name.removeClass(clss.redline);
        }

        $util.text(tempValues.util);
        if (tempValues.util_class) {
            $util.addClass(tempValues.util_class);
        } else {
            $util.removeClass(clss.redlineWarning);
        }

        if (($.trim(tempValues.workgroup)) != $.trim($workgroup.text())) {
            if (tempValues.workgroup != selected && selected != 'All') {
                $workgroup.addClass(clss.warning);
            } else {
                $workgroup.removeClass(clss.warning);
            }
        }
        $workgroup.text(tempValues.workgroup);

        toggle_links(i, tempValues);
        $connectionGrid.trigger('updateAll', [false]);
    }
}
```

Some of the code looks to be as little dodgy. For example, `.addClass(tempValues.network_color) ... .removeClass('warning')` means that any added class that is not `warning` will never be removed (unless by some other code). Contrast with `.addClass('redline') ... .removeClass('redline')`, which is guaranteed to add/remove the same class.

Aside: With the tbodys in place, you could consider styling them with eg a border that will expand/contract as the details are shown/hidden.

If performance is still poor, you'll need to investigate deeper to discover what's taking time. Though I'm not an expert driver, Chrome debug tools are very good for diagnosis.

**Edit**

Back to a single `<tbody>` but with `class="info network"`, `class="info boot"`, `class="info check_in"`, in place, try selecting as follows :

```
// Find the parent row
var $tr = $('#' + i); // A parent row

if($tr.length == 0) return; // avoid unnecessary work if element is not found

var $childRows = $tr.nextUntil(".parent"); // the parent's child rows

$network = $childRows.find(selectors.network);
$boot = $childRows.find(selectors.boot);
$check_in = $childRows.find(selectors.checked_in);

$name = $tr.find(selectors.name);
$util = $tr.find(selectors.util);
$workgroup = $tr.find(selectors.workgroup);
```

This will be slightly less efficient than finding elements within tbody containers but still better than finding by ID - and Tablesorter will still work.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Roamer, I will digest and dig in and hopefully see some improvement. Off the initial look it appears to break `tablesorter zebra` widget as well as `tablesorter` sorting, but `tablesorter` filtering is working.  I will provide a more detailed update after digesting

Comment: `$connectionGrid.trigger('updateAll', [false]);`   appears to be the bottle neck.  This is a tablesorter update call.  But I think I need to put the tbody back outside the loop so that I can maintain sorting on the whole table

Comment: Understand - I contributed to Tablesorter a few years ago and had a feeling it was limited to single tbody (same as DataTables I think). But all is not lost, the objective of multiple tbodies was to make for efficient selections, which is still possible by traversing the DOM slightly differently.

Comment: According to the Tablesorter docs, `updateAll` "allows you to update the cache with data from both the thead and tbody of the table", while `update` "only updates the cache from the tbody". As your `writeTableLines()` only addresses the tbody, try `update` and see if it performs better.

Comment: UGH! I had the `updateAll` inside the loop. Such a fool! It now responds to an initial overhead of half a second, + `~.2` seconds per computer... I would still like to learn more about proper DOM navigation using `closest` or `find` with the supplied html for edification and best practice

Comment: Doh! Sorry I should have spotted that. I've added another suggestion regarding selection of elements in the loop. Should work, providing I've not made any mistakes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35265/discussion-between-busturdust-and-roamer-1888).

Comment: the `nextUntil` was the missing link for me. + obviously removing the `updateAll` out of the loop, and on top of that changing it to the simpler `updateCache` call loses some overhead. I can now accept the current theoretical maximum in `~2.5` seconds. Fantastic! Thanks for all your help

Comment: @Busturdust, just spotted your chat invitation. Are you still there?

Answer (score 2):

1. Declare new local variables in local scope instead of global scope with `var` or `let`:

   ```
   var selector = ...
   let selector = ...
   for (var i in tempRows) { ... }
   ```

   Otherwise they'll become member variables of the global scope which is typically the `window` object.
2. There's a CSS shorthand to select elements by attribute `id`: prefix the attribute value with a `#` sign:

   ```
   selector = "#" + i;
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   selector = "[id='"+i+"']";
   ```

   If you want to avoid potential escaping issues, you can also use:

   ```
   selector = document.getElementById(i.toString())
   ```
3. Reuse jQuery objects that refer to the same (set of) element(s):

   ```
   selector = $("#"+i);
   [...]
   selector.find(".name").addClass();
   [...]
   selector.find(".name").removeClass();
   ```

   or better yet:

   ```
   [...]
   selector_name = selector.find(".name");
   [...]
   selector_name.addClass();
   [...]
   selector_name.removeClass();
   ```

   The same goes for the variables `network_selector`, `boot_selector`, etc.

Comment: Thanks David, these are some useful tips and I believe they will help streamline the function. Allow me some time to restructure and I will accept. Thanks for the help

Comment: can you please elaborate why `selector = document.getElementById(i.toString())` is better than `selector = "[id='"+i+"']";` I would think this adds an extra DOM access?

Comment: Look at what the code is doing later with the value of `selector`: `$("[id='foobar']")`, `$("#foobar")` and require exactly one DOM look-up just like `$(document.getElementById("foobar"))`, but the latter is more robust in the defense against programming mistakes or attacks, if the ID string is not a literal or even comes from user input.

Comment: still takes about 2 seconds per item :( Ill have to revisit again tomorrow. Thanks again for the tips

Comment: 2 seconds per item is way too long. I would expect to be seeing a few tens of milliseconds per item.

Comment: Im going to leave this question open for now in hopes of some performance tips

Comment: Are you sure, you're only measuring the DOM manipulation time for a single item? Or do you maybe also measure the time to fetch it over the network and/or rendering the new DOM? Please provide your updated code in a follow-up question referring to this question and stating what you have tried already and what and potentially how you're measuring exactly.