# Large table updates using AJAX in Internet Explorer 11 (Cont'd)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

Previous topic: [Large table updates using AJAX in Internet Explorer 11](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/118678/large-table-updates-using-ajax-in-internet-explorer-11?noredirect=1#comment221109_118678)

For the functions included here, I have taken the advice of the previous answer and incorporated it in the restructure, but am still experiencing **huge latency** of about **2 seconds per computer record**.

I am lead to believe that this is more an issue with the structure of the DOM. I have added the HTML to this post. Could anyone advise if there may be a more appropriate table structure / access method that might better suit my needs?

```js
function writeTableLines(tempRows){
    /* This Function takes care of updating the text and coloring of
    network name
    Boot time
    chck in time
    workgroup
    utilization
    All other values are not dynamically written.
    */
    for( i in tempRows){
        var tempValues = tempRows[i];
        // For Row
        var selector = $(document.getElementById(i.toString()));
        var name_selector = selector.find(".name");
        var network_selector = $(document.getElementById(i.toString()+'_network'));  //"[id='"+i+"_network']";
        var boot_selector =  $(document.getElementById(i.toString()+'_boot'));                //"[id='"+i+"_boot']";
        var check_in_selector =   $(document.getElementById(i.toString()+'_checked_in'));//"[id='"+i+"_checked_in']";
        var util_selector = selector.find('.util').find('a');
        var workgroup_selector = selector.find('.workgroup').find('a');

  network_selector.text(tempValues['network']);

  if (tempValues['network_color']){
      network_selector.addClass(tempValues['network_color']);
      name_selector.addClass(tempValues['network_color']);
  }else{
      network_selector.removeClass('warning');
       name_selector.removeClass('warning');
  }

        // Boot Time

  boot_selector.text(tempValues['boot']);
  if (tempValues['boot_color']){
      boot_selector.addClass(tempValues['boot_color']);
     name_selector.addClass(tempValues['boot_color'])
  }else{
      boot_selector.removeClass('issue');
      name_selector.removeClass('issue');
  }

  // Last Checked In Timestamp

  check_in_selector.text(tempValues['checked_in']);
  if (tempValues['service_unresponsive']){
      check_in_selector.addClass('redline');
      name_selector.addClass('redline');
  }else{
      check_in_selector.removeClass('redline');
      name_selector.removeClass('redline');
  }


  util_selector.text(tempValues['util'])
   if (tempValues['util_class']){
            util_selector.addClass(tempValues['util_class']);
        }else{
            util_selector.removeClass('redline warning');
        }



        if (($.trim(tempValues['workgroup'])) != $.trim(workgroup_selector.text())){
            if ((tempValues['workgroup'] != selected) && (selected != 'All')){
       workgroup_selector.addClass('warning');
      }else{
       workgroup_selector.removeClass('warning');
      }
  }
        workgroup_selector.text(tempValues['workgroup'])
  toggle_links(i, tempRows[i]);
  $('#connectionGrid').trigger('updateAll', [false]);
   }
}
function disable_links(computer){
 var links = document.getElementsByClassName("pclinks_"+computer);
 var myLength = links.length;
 for(var i = 0; i < myLength ;i++){
  links[i].removeAttribute("href");
  $(links[i]).addClass('disabled_link').removeClass('enabled_link');
  if (links[i].id == 'refresh'){
   continue;
  }
  links[i].onclick = function(){
   alert("Currently Offline");
  }
    }
}

function enable_links(computer, network){
 var links = document.getElementsByClassName("pclinks_"+computer);
 var myLength = links.length;
 for(var i = 0 ; i < myLength ; i++){
   if (links[i].id == 'refresh'){
    links[i].onclick = function(){ refresh(this)};
    continue;
   }
   links[i].href = "file://///"+network+"/MM"+links[i].id;
   $(links[i]).removeClass('disabled_link').addClass('enabled_link');
      $(links[i]).prop("onclick", null);
  }
}


function toggle_links(computer, row){
 if(row['online'] == false){
  disable_links(computer);
 }else{
  enable_links(computer, row['network']);
 }
}
```

```html
{% extends 'directory/base.html' %} 
{% block content %}

<div id="tabs">
    <ul id="gaugeList">
        {% for workgroup in context['workgroup_list'] %}
        <li><h3>
        <a class="gaugeCell" id="{{ workgroup.shorthand }}" href="#tabs-{{ workgroup.shorthand }}"></a>
        </h3></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <div id="gridBox" class="scrollable">
        <table id="connectionGrid" class="tablesorter">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Computer</th>
                    <th>Workgroup</th>
                    <th>C:\ Drive %</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th class="clearall button" onclick="hideRows()">Clear All</th>
                    <th onclick="collapseListener()" id="collapserows" class="collapseall button">Collapse All</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="connectionBody">
                {% for computer in context['computer_list'] %} 
                {% if (computer.visible == True or current_user.is_admin) and computer.active_drive is not none %}
                <tr id="{{computer.name}}" class="parent">
                    <td rowspan="1" class="type">
                        <a href="#" class="toggle">{{ computer.station_type if computer.station_type else 'Enter Data'}}</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="name">
                        <a href="#" id="name" class="toggle">{{computer.name}}</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="workgroup">
                        <a href="#" id="{{computer.name}}_workgroup" class="innerworkgroup toggle">{{computer.active_drive.workgroup.shorthand}}</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="util">
                        <a href="#" class="toggle" id="{{computer.name}}_util">{{ computer.active_drive.percentage_full if computer.active_drive.percentage_full else 'Check Service'}}</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a id="{{computer.name}}_Users" class="enabled_link pclinks_{{computer.name}}" href="file://///{{ computer.active_drive.name }}/MMUsers" target="_blank">Users</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a id="{{computer.name}}_Projects" class="enabled_link pclinks_{{computer.name}}" href="file://///{{ computer.active_drive.name }}/MMProjects" target="_blank">Projects</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a id="{{computer.name}}_attic" class="enabled_link pclinks_{{computer.name}}" href="file://///{{ computer.active_drive.name}}/MMAttic" target="_blank">Attic</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a id="{{computer.name}}_pcusers" class="enabled_link pclinks_{{computer.name}}" href="file://///{{ computer.active_drive.name }}/MMPCUsers" target="_blank">Desktops</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <img src="{{url_for('static',filename='images/refresh.png')}}" title="Service restart may take up to a minute" id="{{computer.name}}_refresh" class="pclinks_{{computer.name}}" onclick="refresh(this)" target="_blank">
                        </img>
                    </td>
                    <tr class="tablesorter-childRow">
                        <td class="label dualboot topitem" colspan="1">Dual Boot</td>
                        <td class="info dualboot topitem" colspan="1" >
                            {{ 'Yes' if computer.dual_boot == True else 'No' }}
                        </td>

                        <td class="label topitem" colspan="3" style="text-align:center;">{{computer.active_drive.image_version}}</td>

                        <td class="label topitem" colspan="2">Media Composer</td>
                        <td class="info topitem" colspan="2">{{computer.active_drive.media_composer_version}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="tablesorter-childRow">
                        <td class="label" colspan="1">Network Name</td>
                        <td class="info" colspan="1" id="{{computer.name}}_network">{{ computer.active_drive.name }}</td>

                        <td class="label">Model</td>
                        <td class="info" colspan="2">
                            {{ computer.model if computer.model else 'Check Service' }}</td>
                        <td class="label" colspan="2">Interplay Access</td>
                        <td class="info" colspan="2">{{computer.active_drive.access_version}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="tablesorter-childRow">
                        <td class="label">Room</td>
                        <td class="info" colspan="1">
                            {% if computer.room %} {{ computer.room }} ({{computer.room.description}}) {% else %} Enter Data {% endif %}
                        </td>

                        <td class="label" colspan="1">Edit Service</td>
                        <td class="info" colspan="2">{{computer.active_drive.edit_service_version}}</td>
                        <td class="label" colspan="2">Media Indexer</td>
                        <td class="info " colspan="2">{{computer.active_drive.indexer_version}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="tablesorter-childRow">
                        <td class="label" colspan="1">Phone</td>
                        <td class="info" colspan="1">
                            {{ computer.room.phone_numbers if computer.room.phone_numbers else 'Enter Data'}}</td>

                        <td class="label ">Boot Time</td>
                        <td class="info " colspan="2" id="{{computer.name}}_boot">
                            {% if computer.online == false %} Offline {% else %} {{ computer.active_drive.boot_time if computer.active_drive.boot_time else 'Check Service' }} {% endif %}
                        </td>

                        <td class="label" colspan="2">Transfer Client</td>
                        <td class="info" colspan="2">{{computer.active_drive.transfer_client_version}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="tablesorter-childRow">
                        <td class="label" id="intercomlabel" colspan="1">Intercom</td>
                        <td class="info" colspan="1">
                            {{ computer.room.intercom_numbers if computer.room.intercom_numbers else 'Enter Data' }}
                        </td>
                        <td class="label" colspan="1">Checked-In</td>
                        <td class="info checkin" colspan="2" id="{{computer.name}}_checked_in">
                            {{ computer.active_drive.last_checked_in if computer.active_drive.last_checked_in else 'Check Service' }}
                        </td>
                        <td class="label" colspan="2">Avid ISIS Client</td>
                        <td class="info" colspan="2">{{computer.active_drive.isis_client_version}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="tablesorter-childRow">
                        <td class="label">Notes</td>
                        <td class="info" colspan="1">{{ computer.notes if computer.notes else ''}}</td>
                        <td class="label">Swing Date</td>

                        <td class="info" colspan="2">{{ computer.active_drive.last_changed_workgroup }}</td>

                        <td class="label" colspan="2">Nvidia Driver</td>
                        <td class="info " colspan="2">{{computer.active_drive.graphics_driver_version}}</td>
                   </tr>

                {% endif %} 
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>

    <div id="bottom" class="bottom">
        {% for workgroup in context['workgroup_list'] %}
        <a href="#" id="{{workgroup.shorthand}}" class="show_{{workgroup}}">
{{ workgroup.shorthand }}
</a> {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it has been quite some time since the question was posted and maybe you have found optimizations already but hopefully the review below will be helpful.

#### Selecting elements

In the previous review, [the answer by @Roamer-1888](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/118774/120114) stated the following:

> Searching a whole, large DOM for elements is a real performance killer. When possible, always try to search a fragment, or traverse the DOM relative to a known element.

Yet, it appears that the `writeTableLines()` function still has many calls to `document.getElementById()`. For example, `selector` could be found by utilizing the `<tbody>` element. It would be best to store a reference to that element outside the `for` loop -

```
var tbody = $('#connectionBody');
```

Then `selector` can be found using [`selector.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
var selector = tbody.find('#' + i.toString());
```

Once `selector` has been found, the other child elements (e.g `network_selector`, `boot_selector`, etc.) can be found using `selector.find()` as well...

#### Unique `id` attributes

Inside the functions `disable_links()` and `enable_links()` I see conditional logic like this:

> ```
> if (links[i].id == 'refresh'){
> ```

But looking at the HTML I don't see any element with that *id* attribute. Inside each row I see an element with

> ```
> <img src="{{url_for('static',filename='images/refresh.png')}}" title="Service restart may take up to a minute" id="{{computer.name}}_refresh" class="pclinks_{{computer.name}}" onclick="refresh(this)" target="_blank">
> ```

So unless there is another HTML element that wasn't included in the original post, that conditional code mentioned above would never evaluate to `true`.

Similarly, I noticed in the HTML for the table rows:

> ```
> <td class="name">
>       <a href="#" id="name" class="toggle">{{computer.name}}</a>
> ```

This means that each row has an anchor element with the *id* attribute value `name`. Remember that "*The **id** global attribute defines a unique identifier (ID) which **must be unique in the whole document**.*"<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)</sup>

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id</sub>